# Rails: What is the correct usage of Rails.root.join when pointing to "tmp/caching-dev.txt"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I'm setting up a new Rails project and after giving it an initial tidy with Rubocop, I'm left with a single offense.

Rubop complains:

```
config/environments/development.rb:16:6: C: Please use Rails.root.join('path', 'to') instead.
  if Rails.root.join("tmp/caching-dev.txt").exist?
```

I see that `Rails.root` returns the path of the current project. So I've tried

```
if File.join(Rails.root, "tmp/caching-dev.text").exist?
```

instead. But still, Rubocop complains:

```
config/environments/development.rb:17:6: C: Please use Rails.root.join('path', 'to') instead.
  if File.join(Rails.root, "tmp/caching-dev.text").exist?
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What are the `path` and `root` arguments meant to be? Surely `Rails.root` is the path?!

Comment: `Rails.root` is an instance of [Pathname](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html). The whole point of Pathname is to provide an abstraction that provides cross-platform paths so your code can work on that silly OS that got everything backwards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think Rubocop is suggesting you to do something like this

```
if File.exist?(Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt'))
```

Comment: For me rubocop wants `tmp/whatever.txt` which is rather strange.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, [Pathname](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) and `/` are not used enough.

```
if (Rails.root / 'tmp' / 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
```

Comment: Seems to work on Linux. Does this work on Windows too? For some reason I couldn't find documentation around `/`...

Comment: It uses File.join under the hood (https://apidock.com/ruby/Pathname/plus).  So yes, it is portable to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by config .rubocop.yml:

Style/ExpandPathArguments:
EnforcedStyle: Style/ExpandPathArguments
Enabled: false